# Tentando deixar uma pergunta em loop

Tags: python

Estou tentando deixar uma pergunta em loop para que o usuário responda somente oq o programa está mostrando para ele.

```
for carroEscolhido in carros:
         
        carros = str(input("Digite somente os carros que estão na lista: ")) 
        
while carros not in carroEscolhido:
```

Comment: Precisa melhorar essa pergunta. Fala que é pra digitar os carros que estão na lista. Onde está essa lista. Ideal é colocar o código inteiro. É bom você descrever detalhes da sua dúvida, o que você já fez e o que está dando errado. Que tal visitar o [tour do SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo feedback, vou melhorar nas minhas perguntas e muito agradecido pela sua ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta não está suficientemente clara, considere ser mais especifico na próxima vez. Isto facilita a leitura para que alguém possa identificar o que você deseja e elaborar uma solução.

Se entendi bem, você tem uma lista de carros, como por exemplo:

carros = ['onix', 'argo', 'chronos', 'mareia', 'uno']

E quer que o loop continue até que o input seja um dos carros da lista. Se for isto, segue um exemplo que atenderá sua necessidade:

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Informe o carro: ")
    if user_input in carros:
        break
```

Deste modo, o loop continuará até que o usuário informe um dos carros contidos na lista predefinida por você.

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais eficiente de fazer um loop no python 3 é usando while dessa forma aqui

```py
carros = ['ONIX', 'ARGO', 'UNO', 'JETTA', 'SW4', 'COROLLA', 'GOL']
print(carros)
while True:
    user_resposta = input('Digite somente os carros que estão na lista: ').strip().upper()
    if user_resposta not in carros:
        break
print('Você digitou um carro fora da lista')
```

Nesse codigo acima o while vai repetir infinitamente pois a condição sempre será True, entretando eu coloquei um if que pausa a repetição caso o usuário escreva um carro diferente do que está na lista.

Outra observação importante é que o python é uma linguagem que maiusculos e minusculos fazem diferença, então é sempre bom colocar .upper ou .lower no input para que a resposta do usuário seja sempre maiuscula ou minuscula e a sua lista tem que estar configurada de um desses jeitos.

obs: .strip() que eu coloquei no input foi para que mesmo que o usuário digite espaços desnecessários no inicio e no fim de sua resposta o python salve a resposta dele sem esses espaços.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).